# Bind datagrid with autogeneratecolumn=false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagridview, I am binding this grid with SQL, I have added five rows in datagrid as same in sql with `autogeneratecolumn = false.`.

my code is

```
string qry1 = "select modal,Spec,color,Types,reqQty from godownRequsition where gr='" + txtGr.Text + "'";

dataGridView1.DataSource = DAL.GetdataTable(qry1);
```

the problem is that when I run the program, the rows of datagrid could not show the data. If I  finish all the column in datagrid and autogenerate column is true it show the data..

now I  want to bind the datagrid with my own generated columns not autogenerated.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I suppose you have use DataBind after setting DataSource ?

Comment: please post your Aspx code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the column by your self like this :

```
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.HeaderText = "Lama";
        int indexCol = grid.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: int indexCol = grid.Columns.Add(column);//whats doing code line

Comment: that gives you the index to put content into it (you can put it into a list or something to retrieve it after).

Comment: DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.HeaderText = "Lama";
        int indexCol = grid.Columns.Add(column); //This code add twice column instead of one

Comment: @RaoUsman : The code is correct.  First, the column object is created.  Then it is added to the grid.  It's not like he's calling grid.Columns.Add("Lama");

Comment: @3wic : You didn't set the column name for binding.